# Can´t install jQuery (or other Bower packages) in Visual Studio 2017 using Bower

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, bower

I want to add jQuery to my Visual Studio 2017 project. 
I added a bower.json and a .bowerrc

My bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

My .bowerrc file:

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

I am working with .Net Core 2 and whenever I try to install a Bower package, I get a generic error message. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: @RichieThomas error while installing "jQuery". Would you like to open an errorwindow to see the details? 
Then it says: Error: Unable to parse C:\Users\cleme\source\repos\DutchTreat\DutchTreat\.bowerrc: Unexpected token at parse

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the bower.json or .bowerrc that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

no your wrong not in bower package code.

clear lib directory in pass

> wwwroot/lib

and try again.

Your problem is because you install package but not add in bower.json